# How to customize rolePrefix in Grails using Spring Security plugin?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am working on a `grails 2.3.8` project and trying to customize the `Role Hierarchy`. I am trying to change the default value of `rolePrefix = 'ROLE_'` in `resources.groovy` with `rolePrefix = 'PERM_'`. I understand that to make this work, I need to make the following changes in my `Config.groovy` into something like:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'tpo.core.acl.AdminAccount'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'tpo.core.acl.AdminAccountPermission'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.authority.className = 'tpo.core.acl.Permission'
```

And to establish hierarchy, I need to add this too in my Config.groovy

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.roleHierarchy = ''' 
    PERM_ACCOUNT_ALL > PERM_ACCOUNT_CREATE
    PERM_ACCOUNT_ALL > PERM_ACCOUNT_READ
    PERM_ACCOUNT_ALL > PERM_ACCOUNT_UPDATE
    PERM_ACCOUNT_ALL > PERM_ACCOUNT_DELETE
'''
```

So in my Controller, it is something like,

```
@Secured(['PERM_ACCOUNT_ALL'])
    def index() {
        redirect(action: "list", params: params)
    }
```

When I try to run my application, and access my controller's `index()` action, I was prompted to log in, this is expected because of the presence of @Secured(), but having successfully logged in, I was not yet able to access the `index()` action, and it displayed, Sorry, you're not authorized to view this page. The permission was assigned to the user that I used to logged in, but still, I was not able to access it.

Where am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot more to it than that :)

The reason that the plugin doesn't allow this change is to support the standard voters. Currently there are three styles of strings that can be used to specify access rules - role names, SPeL expressions, and the funky "IS_AUTHENTICATED" ones - `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY`, `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY`, and  `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED`. Additionally there's a new way that was added for the 2.0 release - using a Closure and any arbitrary Groovy code inside of it, but that's unrelated to role names.

Each of the registered voters is queried to determine if they "support" (i.e. can vote on) each of these tokens. The logic is currently rather straightforward - the "IS_AUTHENTICATED_..." strings are handled by one voter, strings starting with "ROLE_" are handled by another, and everything else is assumed to be a SPeL expression.

To be honest, I think since roles would have to have been "registered" at startup anyway (to specify what access rules are allowed for each role in annotations, `Config.groovy`, etc.) that the role voter could do more than just check that the string starts with some prefix - it could look at its collection of known role names. So it probably wouldn't be too much work to add support for custom role prefixes for the 2.0 release, and I'll look into that. But for now, the plugin is as customizable as much as possible in every way except for this one exception.

Comment: thank you so much for the response. We are able to customize the role prefix in grails 2.0.4 before, but now, following same customization, I can no longer apply it using grails 2.3.8, even when using same spring security core version which is 1.2.7.3. I am lost o_o